# How can I run other Twisted Services and scrapy's Spiders inside the same reactor?

Tags: python, scrapy, twisted

The python [Scrapy](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/overview.html) package uses [Twisted](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twisted_(software)). I would like to run a set of scrapy's Spiders and other twisted services inside the same twisted reactor. I think I need to run the spiders inside a twisted service, the set of services would make the [Twisted application](https://twisted.readthedocs.io/en/twisted-16.6.0/core/howto/application.html). How I should do it?

Comment: consider using `CrawlProcess` or `CrawlRunner` https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/practices.html. `CrawlRunner` should do what you need

Comment: @maestro.inc Thanks for the comment. I already readed that, I think I need to use the CrawlerRunner so I can have more control of what's happening with the spiders. I think I can use twisted's [MultiService](https://howto.lintel.in/implement-multiservice-twisted/) but I don't know how to turn the scraping process into a twisted service.